# Is it possible to debug angularjs in MVC in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Annoyance: I'm working on my application, and I find a bug. I instantly think 'Time to debug it!', and I open Chrome, and then open Dev Tools, and then use its rather inelegant debug tools.

Desire: I'd love to be able to: open my browser, set Studio to debug mode, breakpoint a few places in my controller.js file, and start stepping through things **in Visual Studio**.

I'm using **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate** and **Chrome** - can it be done?

Comment: [Client-Side Script Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry - I see I completely forgot to mention, and I'll update the question to reflect it, but I'm using Chrome as my browser, because I'm pretty sure IE is just a joke MS plays on everyone.

Comment: ["Debugging with Visual Studio"](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/vs-addin) on the Chrome Developer website.

Answer (score 5):

Use Internet Explorer as default browser
in Visual Studio instead. It works!

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. Debugging in Visual Studio (2015 at least) has only worked with Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that it was down-voted because the question specifically indicates CHROME as the browser. Snarky answers aren't really helpful. And I asked the question, and still didn't down-vote this answer - I just ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a VS Code extension to debug your JavaScript code in the Google Chrome browser, or other targets that support the Chrome Debugging Protocol.

[VS chrome debugging add-in](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)